# Using AND operator in the if condition in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, operators

I am working on a wordpress website in which I am adding class when h1 elements are empty (as shown below) meaning when there is no content inside `.featured-block__tag` and 
`.featured-block__title` classes.

```
<h1 class="featured-block__title"></h1>
<h1 class="featured-block__tag"></h1>
```

Here is the logic I have used in jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    if ($(".featured-block__title").is(":empty")) {
        $(".img-fit").addClass("opacity-pointeight");
    }
})
```

The above code only works when there is no content inside `.featured-block__title` class.

**Problem Statement**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the code above so that it checks both 
for `.featured-block__tag` and `.featured-block__title` classes.

Also, `.featured-block__tag` show `::before` selector when there is no content inside it.

[image]

Comment: `if( $(".featured-block__title").is(":empty") && $(".featured-block__tag").is(":empty") ) `

Comment: Hi, `featured-block_tag` has ::before selector as well. Is there any we can ignore it ?

Comment: `featured-block__tag` class is showing `::before` selector when there is no content inside it. Is there any way we can ignore it ?

Comment: @Sushanth-- I have updated the question. Let me know how it looks.

Comment: Why don't you use `$(".featured-block__title").html() === ""` instead of checking for `is(":empty")`? I think it makes much more sense. and you wouldn't have any problem with `:before`

Comment: `$0` is just a helper that is used for debugging. it will always point to the last item you have selected with code.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `$(".featured-block__title").html() === ""` instead of checking for `is(":empty")`?

I think it makes much more sense, and you wouldn't have any problem with `:before`

Try it like this:

```
$(function() {
    if($(".featured-block__tag").html() === "" &&
        $(".featured-block__title").html() === "") {
        $(".img-fit").addClass("opacity-pointeight");
    }
})
```

Comment: @flash sorry, I'm here now